# PHP: calculate popularity/frequency of an item sold from multimensional Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array extracted from my mysql that stores item_id, day that the item_id has been sold or not sold, and the price
my query is something like

```
select * from freq_history_sales 
where freq_item_id = 123
```

and the output example is given below

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [freq_item_id] => 123      // item ID  / sku number etc..
            [freq_end] => 2016-05-06   // when the sale ended
            [freq_status] => sold      // if sold or not
            [freq_price] => 175        // price sold
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [freq_item_id] => 123
            [freq_end] => 2016-05-06
            [freq_status] => notsold
            [freq_price] => 225
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [freq_item_id] => 123
            [freq_end] => 2016-05-10
            [freq_status] => notsold
            [freq_price] => 225
        )

...etc...
```

I would like to record the time, sold/not sold on that specific day, and final price or items and then calculate a sort of frequency/popularity of this item

I am asking if this is something that can be done in PHP. I that is the case, how to transform that frequency in a sort of index 1 to 10 so that I can judge the popularity.

Comment: PHP is turing complete, so as a matter of principle you can do *anything* with it, yes. It's a bit impossible to help you here in a reasonable scope, since we can hardly suggest what algorithm exactly you might be interested in.

Comment: From my perspective, there are not enough information provided: What does notsold mean? I guess that means that there are >= 1 copies of that item left in stock? What does freq_end mean? If the item is sold, is this the date it run out of stock? If the item is notsold, is that the day the item got into stock? Do you have any numbers like copies sold or copies left in stock?

Comment: @Marc no i don't have those info... i was thinking just to calc how many sold per day vs. not sold. and say today only 1out of 3 sold. then tomorrow will be 3 out of 3. etc... so basically if an item sells only 1 out fo 3 evey day will have a lower index than an item that sells all the availability every day...

Comment: probably it's not php the issue here... i just need to figure out the correct algoritm...

Comment: Okay, we can do that. Where is the product ID? If it's the array index, how do you store the data of multiple days per item?

Comment: i didn't post/need the ID here because i was assuming this array is only for one specific id..  this is the array output from mysql where i basically already selected the history of only one ID... does make sense?

Comment: @Marc ok i updated/added info to the question...

Comment: You can us a very simplified data structure and are asking about vague things like calculating frequency/popularity without explaining how you want to calculate this.  There is not enough info to go from here and probably not really even a programming question. Maybe this question is better suited for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: *calculate a sort of frequency/popularity of this item*, *sort of index 1 to 10*: you'll have to provide the details of the *sort of* part. Without clear specifications a programmer should not even start to code.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes probably you right, but I feel here people respond faster... i personally feel splitting StackOverflow in siloed website has been a huge error and UX flaw because users don't think in buckets of problems but as problems with tags (think Quora)